# Doctrine MOD - even date doctrine with symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

With doctrine i have generate a controller to show a movie title.

I have this error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 52: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=,
>   !=, got '%'

The First code work but the second code dont show even year.
Why?

```
/** Mostrare i film usciti tra il 1980 e il 1990
 *
 * @Route("/findBetweenYears/{yearStart}/{yearStop}", name ="movie_between")
 * @Method("GET")
 *
*/
public function showMovieBetweenAction($yearStart,$yearStop){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->select('m')
  ->from(Movie::class,'m')
  ->where('m.year >= 1980 and m.year <=1990');
  $movies = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  return $this->render('movie/yearshow.html.twig',array(
   'movies' => $movies,
  ));

}
/** Mostrare i film usciti in un anno pari
 *
 * @Route("/findEvenYears/{year}", name = "movie_even")
 * @Method("GET")
 *
*/
public function showMovieYearEven(){
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
  $qb->select('m')
  ->from(Movie::class,'m')
  ->where('m.year % 2 = 0');
  $movies = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
  return $this->render('movie/yeareven.html.twig',array(
    'movies' => $movies
  ));
}
```

Comment: even years,sorry

Comment: Do you have an error or something in the log?

Comment: what is the query in the debug bar? what is the result of your query, an empty array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine `mod` DQL is defined in [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions) as

> MOD(a, b) - Return a MOD b.

Meaning you should use it as

```
  ->where('MOD(m.year, 2) = 0')
```